# MySQL Syntax Error (Completely new to this)

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( start_date_time ) AS
MONTH, SUM (
CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time ) = '2011' AND YEAR( u.registered) = '2011'
THEN oi.qty
END )
AS '2011', SUM (


CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time ) = '2012' AND YEAR( u.registered) = '2012'
THEN oi.qty
END )
AS '2012',  SUM (


CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time) = '2013' AND YEAR( u.registered) = '2013'
THEN oi.qty
END )
) AS '2013' 

FROM order_items oi INNER JOIN events e ON oi.eventid = e.eventid INNER JOIN company_campaign ON e.event_campaign_id = company_campaign.campaignid
     INNER JOIN company
          ON company.companyid = company_campaign.companyid
     INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.userID = company.createdby
WHERE start_date_time > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH( start_date_time ) ASC
```

I get the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS '2013' FROM order_items oi INNER JOIN events e ON oi.eventid = e.eventid ' at line 18

I'm completely new to SQL and the join represented my greatest achievement to date, but this has completely stumped me. Sometimes I use the wrong type of ' but it's the right one here. Also sometimes I put a , at the end of the query. I'm using MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an extra closing parenthesis (just before AS 2013) is causing this.

Try:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( start_date_time ) AS
MONTH, 

SUM ( CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time ) = '2011' AND YEAR( u.registered ) = '2011'
THEN oi.qty END )
AS '2011', 

SUM ( CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time ) = '2012' AND YEAR( u.registered ) = '2012'
THEN oi.qty END )
AS '2012',  

SUM ( CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time) = '2013' AND YEAR( u.registered ) = '2013'
THEN oi.qty END )
AS '2013' 

FROM order_items oi INNER JOIN events e ON oi.eventid = e.eventid INNER JOIN company_campaign ON e.event_campaign_id = company_campaign.campaignid
     INNER JOIN company
          ON company.companyid = company_campaign.companyid
     INNER JOIN users u
          ON u.userID = company.createdby
WHERE start_date_time > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH( start_date_time ) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. That error has gone, however I received another error saying db.sum did not exist, the problem here was using a space in-between sum and ( which I removed, works perfectly now! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Extra close bracket before 'As 2013'

> ) AS '2013'

Remove that and it should be fine.

Just to add - it always makes it much easier reading queries if you separate out your bracketed sections. Takes a bit longer and adds more lines but it will make it so much easier to read (and to spot syntax issues) for other people or for yourself when you come back to it in the future.

e.g. written like this it is immediately obvious where the problem is -

```
SELECT 
MONTHNAME( start_date_time ) AS MONTH, 
SUM 
(
    CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time ) = '2011' AND YEAR( u.registered) = '2011'
    THEN oi.qty
    END 
) AS '2011', 
SUM 
(
    CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time ) = '2012' AND YEAR( u.registered) = '2012'
    THEN oi.qty
    END 
) AS '2012',  
SUM 
(
    CASE WHEN YEAR( start_date_time) = '2013' AND YEAR( u.registered) = '2013'
    THEN oi.qty
    END 
)
) AS '2013'
```

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it, other answer is correct too.